# Understanding the following code

Tags: arrays, calloc

Give this code:

```
int solution(int X, int A[], int N) {
    int *jumps = calloc(X+1, sizeof(int));
    int counter = 0;
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<N; i++) {
        if(A[i]<=X && *(jumps+A[i])!=1) {
            *(jumps+A[i])=1;
           if(++counter==X) {
               return i;
           }
        }
    }

    free(jumps);
    return -1;
}
```

Here is what I think I know:

1) `int *jumps = calloc(X+1, sizeof(int));`
   This is making an array storing X+1 elements of an int type.  Since it's
   `calloc` they are all initialized as 0.

2) `if(A[i]<=X && *(jumps+A[i])!=1)`
This if statement's condition is that the element of `A` at index i is less than or equal to `X` and the second part I am confused with. I am totally confused what `*(jumps+A[i])!=1)` means. I know that whatever `*(jumps+A[i])` is cannot equal 1.

3) `if(++counter==X)` 
This also confuses me.  I'm not sure what `++` does in front of `counter`. I thought `++` was used as adding an increment of 1 to something. Also, how does `counter` change? If given the example (5,[1,3,1,4,2,3,5,4]) it changes to 5 but I don't understand why.

Comment: Sorry first time posting.  I tried to make it look nicer but I don't know why its all mushed together.

Answer (score 0):

So here is what i understand :

1. every value in A that is superior to X are ignored. (`A[i] <= X`)
2. every duplicate value in A are ignored : this is the purpose of `(jumps+A[i])` statements.
3. lastly it will return the index of the current loop if your A array contains at least X unique values inferior to X.

Conclusion : if X is 10. Then it will return the index of A when the function will have found every value from 0 to 9 once whatever their order is. If not found return -1. The ++counter make it so it will stop a 9 and not 10.